# Is storing a stack variable in a member vector valid use of a vector?

Tags: c++11, vector, heap-memory, stack-memory

Actually, I am confronted with a code base and have a questions concerning the `std::vector` concerning stack and heap.

Somewhere in a member function I encounter some code similar to this:

Member declaration:

```
//member variable in DataHelper class
std::vector<Data::Point> mDataPoints;
```

Member function:

```
void DataHelper::LoadData(int nPoints)
{
    //mDataPoints is a member variable
    mDataPoints.reserve(nPoints); 

    for (UINT i = 0; i < nPoints; i++) 
    {
        Data::Point point; //some data class
        point.X = 1; //dummy values
        point.Y = 2;
        point.Z = 3;

        mDataPoints.push_back(point);
    }
}
```

So the `Data::Points` are stored in the vector for later use.

I thought that the `Data::Point point;` is allocated on the stack and that it's storage for later use in this sense will lead to errors. Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, when you do a `push_pack` in a `std::vector`, you copy the data points. So, you will have 2 identical instances, one in the heap and the other one in the vector.

You have to make sure that your `Data::Point` implements a copy constructor if needed (for instance, if contains pointers).

Comment: Ah I see, and thanks for the heads up on the copy-constructor/pointers!